# esxi upgrade - Upgrade VIB(s) "loadesx" is required for the transaction

Tags: vmware-esxi

### Applying a esxi patch (from HPE custom esxi 7.0 to esxi 7.0U2c) fails

esxcli software vib update -d /full/path/VMware-ESXi-7.0U2c-18426014-depot.zip

### Error message

[InstallationError]
Upgrade VIB(s) "loadesx" is required for the transaction. Please use a depot of a complete set od ESXi VIBs.

### Server hardware

HPE gen10

Any clue why I get the error message?

Comment: Can you explain how you are updating your esxi? With a custom iso? Or appling from cli? Sometimes custom iso makes problem with lost vibs

Comment: usually the esxi needs a custom iso. This time no custom iso was available. In order to fix an annoying bug we had to apply a general vmware patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general patch provided by vmware could applied by the following commands

Select one desired ImageProfile from the available ImageProfile list:

```
esxcli software sources profile list -d /full/path/VMware-ESXi-7.0U2c-18426014-depot.zip
```

Apply the ImageProfile with the profile parameter -p:

```
esxcli software profile update -d /full/path/VMware-ESXi-7.0U2c-18426014-depot.zip -p <ImageProfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gerald
We have exactly the same hardware, HPE custom file and the same problem.
I have worked with VMware tech support and they have experienced this problem before.

Downloading the HPE custom VMware-ESXi-7.0.3-19193900-HPE-703.0.0.10.8.6.3-Jan2022-Synergy-depot.zip file and upgrading a host with this zip file using esxcli software vib -d /path/VMware-ESXi-7.0.3-19193900-HPE-703.0.0.10.8.6.3-Jan2022-Synergy-depot.zip generates the loadesx error.

Solution:

1. Download VMware-ESXi-7.0.3-19193900-HPE-703.0.0.10.8.6.3-Jan2022-Synergy-depot.ISO
2. Mount as Virtual CD/DVD
3. Boot host on this ISO
4. Select upgrade

After the reboot, I joined the host to the vSphere and NSX cluster and it created the vmkernel adapters automatically and join the clusters without errors.

Comment: your right, this is the way we used to apply HPE custom patches. Since there was no custom patch from HPE for several months for Version 7.0U2c, we had to do the above stated workaround.